# How to handle 404 errors with Ruby HTTP::Net?

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to parse web pages but I sometimes get 404 errors. Here's the code I use to get the web page:

```
result = Net::HTTP::get URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
```

How do I test if `result` is a 404 error code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
result = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) { |http| http.get(uri.path) }
puts result.code
puts result.body
```

That will print the status code followed by the body.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but result.status didn't work. Instead, I checked result.class.name == "HTTPOK", it does the trick :-)

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `result.code`, not `result.status`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Note: URI is in module `net/http`

Answer (score 1):

As you know, your code will always return the response body, whether there is an error or not.  In order to test the response code, use Theo's answer, and the following if statement, for example:

```
if result.code.to_i < 400
  puts "success"
end
```

This example converts the code (which is a string) to an integer, and treats redirects and various 200 codes as successful.

See this for the various codes returned:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the response:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(url))
error = response.is_a?(Net::HTTPNotFound)
result = response.body
```