# Ruby Open-URI library aborted in 404 HTTP error code

Tags: ruby, open-uri, net-http

I use OpenURI library.

```
object = open("http://example.com")
```

If http://example.com server code response is equals to 200 my program acts as I expected.
But if http://example.com server response code is equals to 400 (or other) then script aborts with OpenURI::HTTPError: 404 Not Found.
I can avoid this if I use 'begin-rescue' construction and handle 'HTTPError exception'.
Is this a correct way?
Should I use Net/Http library instead of OpenURI to handle all cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rescuing the `OpenURI::HTTPError` is perfectly reasonable. See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7495389/289274

But if you would rather not deal with exception handling, here's how you can do it with `Net::HTTP`: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797443/289274

Comment: Sadly, it also looks like `OpenURI::HTTPError` does not include any content that might have been returned from the request either (like an explanation from the server, beyond a status code).